# assigning calculated priority to high, medium or low

Tags: excel

I have created a formula that automatically calculates priorities of certain items based on the relative benefit & risk of those items. Inspired by the article found here: https://www.processimpact.com/articles/prioritizing.pdf

But now I would like to automatically assign a value of "High", "Medium" or "Low" based on the calculated value. However, I'm clueless as to how to get started. My best guess is calculating the median and then calculation how much above or below the value is but I just can't seem to figure it out. Can anybody help me?

An example of what would be the desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: What range of calculated values do you get? Is it continuous? What distribution of High, Medium and Low do you want? Based on trying to get 3 equal sized groups, or based on a fix percentage of priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it using the Rank function

The RANK function in Excel returns the order (or rank) of a numeric value compared to other values in the same list. In other words, it tells you which value is the highest, the second highest, etc.

Then I do a COUNTA to find out how many non-blank cells there are and divide that number by 3 and then I simply check how the rank compares to the count with the following logic:

```
Rank > (Count / 3) * 2 (so more than 2/3) = Low
Rank > (Count / 3) (so more than 1/3) = Medium
Rank < (Count / 3) (so less than 1/3) = High
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not read the pdf.
Just to get a "High" for a 3 you can use this:

```
=CHOOSE(C4,"Low","Medium","High")
```

[image]

Comment: well, in real live the numbers won't be as clean as 1,2,3, rather it will be 0,85, 1,68...
However, I'm now playing around with the RANK function and that seems to get me in the right direction